# Bash not evaluating variable name properly

Tags: bash

I changed directory name of my log file to include `$$` (pid) of the bash script. If I add `$$` to the directory name, the following expression fails to execute.

```
command $@ >> $log 2>> $log;
```

```
#Initial line that works 
log="$work/$1";
```

```
#Modified with $$ - didn't work
log="$work/$$/$1";
```

Comment: Does the `$work/$$` directory exist before you run that?

Answer (score 1):

"didn't work" is a vague description of the problem.  One issue that I spot is that generally one cannot write to a directory that does not yet exist.  `mkdir` would solve this:

```
log="$work/$$/$1"
mkdir -p "$work/$$"
command $@ >>$log 2>>$log
```